# Converting var generating query into strongly typed data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

My controller implicitly creates var x as so:

```
 var x = from sem in db.Semesters
         join ss in db.StudentSemesters on sem.Id equals ss.SemesterId into sss
                from ss in sss.Where(ss => ss.StudentId == id).DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new
                {
                    SemsterName = sem.Name,
                    SemesterId = sem.Id,
                    IsAssociated = ss.StudentId != null
                };
```

Instead of passing this data to the view as is, I want to pass it in as a strongly typed businessmodel called StudentSemesterAssociation (members: string SemesterName, int SemesterId, bool StudentIsAssociated) which is used in a viewmodel.

How do I adapt the var generating query above so as to return StudentSemesterAssociation?

ViewModel.StudentSemesterAssociation = ???

regards, Guy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your class name after the `new` keyword in the `select` part of your query:

```
 var x = from sem in db.Semesters
         join ss in db.StudentSemesters on sem.Id equals ss.SemesterId into sss
                from ss in sss.Where(ss => ss.StudentId == id).DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new StudentSemesterAssociation 
                {
                    SemsterName = sem.Name,
                    SemesterId = sem.Id,
                    IsAssociated = ss.StudentId != null
                };
```

This will make `x` type `IEnumerable<StudentSemesterAssociation>` instead of a collection of anonymous types.

And btw. `var` does not make your variable weakly typed. You should read about the [`var` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383973.aspx) and implicitly typed local variables.